# Check with jsonschema if path is valid

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am trying to write a json schema including the feature to check if a path is valid and exist.

For example I want to validate this json:

```
{
  "paths": ["/path/to_check", "../path/not/valid", "../../path/exists"]
}
```

My current schema is:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
     "paths": {
       "type": "array",
       "items": {
         "type": "string"
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to indicate that items must contain valid/existing paths?

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex, but there's no way to determine if a path is a real path according to a file system. JSON Schema works with JSON data... that's all, nothing more. It has no notion of a file system.

Answer (score 1):

JSON schema is good for syntactic validation and is able to handle some types of semantic validation. However, checking the validity of file path is a semantic validation involving the computing system whereas what is an allowed format of file path can be treated syntactic. Pydantic is basically a code where you can implement any validation logic so easier to cover semantic validation in general.

https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been googling for the same thing and was coming to the same conclusion that [@Relequestual posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60174307/713980) (who is the authority on such things).

What may be of interest is that the [pydantic](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/) library extends their JSON Schema with a bunch of [extensions for complex `string` sub-types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#json-schema-types), including `file-path`, `directory-path` and `path` (and many, many more).

This could be useful either directly, or to adopt as a quasi-standard for a custom implementation.